# How to move to next token in JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, tablelayout

```
    else if (cmd.equals("five"))
    {
        infixInput.setText("5");
    }
    else if (cmd.equals("six"))
    {
        infixInput.setText("6");
    }
```

So I have it set where when you press a calc button, the number is displayed on the infix textfield, but if I type 5, then 6 for example, the 6 will just replace the 5. How do I tell it to move over a space when a button is pressed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try changing `infixInput.setText("6");` to:

```
String text = infixInput.getText() + "6";
infixInput.setText(text);
```

This will append the "6" to the end of the text already displayed in the text field.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your text field is not editable you can just append the text using code like the following:

```
infixInput.replaceSelection( "6" );
```

This code will insert the text into the Document (at the caret position, which will be add the end).

I find this approach is more accurate in case you ever use a DocumentListener on the text field since it will only fire an event for the text inserted, not the text removed and added.